# Would this be called a pseudo class selector or an adjacent selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was reading an article at
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

When you check out the demo at Section 17, you get this selector:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

Section 17 covers the pseudo class selector, but this selector seems like an adjacent selector to me. What would you call it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is called anything, it is just a combination of a pseudo class (`:checked`) and a adjacent sibling selector (`+ label`).
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The :checked bit is a pseudo class selector and the + bit is the adjacent selector